# Is necessary to git ignore .expo-shared folder in react native project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I started using react native 2 months ago , and when i create i project by expo init, I see that **.expo-shared** is not ignored, and it seems like it contains someting like a token,
so as a newbie with a web development background, I wanna know if it is okay to push it to the public repository.

Answer (score 18):

There's a README in that folder which says:

```
> Why do I have a folder named ".expo-shared" in my project?

The ".expo-shared" folder is created when running commands that produce state that is intended to be shared with all developers on the project. For example, "npx expo-optimize".

> What does the "assets.json" file contain?

The "assets.json" file describes the assets that have been optimized through "expo-optimize" and do not need to be processed again.

> Should I commit the ".expo-shared" folder?

Yes, you should share the ".expo-shared" folder with your collaborators.
```

So that should answer your question

Comment: I didn't have that file, but I can find [something like it in the expo-cli repo](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/db62b06e48c532944784006ef14fc691687e91a1/packages/expo-optimize/src/assets.ts#L35-L45).

Answer (score -3):

I have not git-ignored mine and all is well, but as this is an expo internal folder, you could add it to the git ignore file without problems.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69546987/39396).